# Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context

Tags: php

I know this question has been asked a thousand times but i still dont get why this is not working,

I am trying to create three classes, The first is the **connection** class

```
<?php

namespace Core;

/**
 * 
 */
class connect
{
        private const DB_NAME = "vp_test";
        private const DB_USER = "root";
        private const DB_PASSWORD = "";
        private const DB_HOST = "localhost";

    function __construct()
    {

        $con= mysqli_connect(self::DB_HOST, self::DB_USER, self::DB_PASSWORD,self::DB_NAME);

        if (!$con){

             die("connection error: ". mysql_connect_error());
        }

    }
}
```

> second class is the model class

```
<?php

namespace Core;

require "autoload.php";

use Core\Connect;
/**
 * 
 */
class Model
{
    private $con;
    public $table;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->con = new Connect;
        $this->table;

    }

    public function all(){

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM {$this->table}";

        return self::execute($sql);

    }

    public function query($select, $where = false){

        if($where){

            $sql = "SELECT {$select} FROM {$this->table} {$where}";

        }
        else{

            $sql = "SELECT {$select} FROM {$this->table}";
        }

        return self::execute($sql);

    }

    // fetch a single record
    public function find($id){

        $find =self::query("*", "WHERE id = {$id}");

        return $find;
    }

    private function execute($sql){

        $query = mysqli_query($this->con, $sql);

        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

        return $row;
    }
}
```

> The third is the user class  which extends the model class

```
<?php

namespace App;

require "./Core/autoload.php";

use Core\Model;

/**
 * 
 */

class User extends Model
{
    private $con;
    private $model;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->model = new Model;
        $this->model->table = "users";


    }

    public static function getUsers(){


        $users = self::all();

        return $users;


    }

    public static function getOneLevel($level){

        $level = self::query("*", "WHERE level = {$level}");
        return $level; 
    }

    public static function getLevel($id){

        $level = self::query("level", "WHERE id= {$id}");

    }

    public static function getParent($id){
        $child = self::find($id);
        $id = self::query("id", "WHERE username = {$child["sponsor_username"]}");

        $parent = self::find($id);

    }

    public static function getChildren($id){

        $parent = self::find($id);

        $child = self::query("*", "WHERE sponsor_username ={$parent["username"]} ");
    }


}
```

I Want the user class to instantiate the model class then pass the table name, but it keeps giving errors, like the one above, I have heavily edited the previous class and I am still as oblivious as the what the problem is, I know of this can only be used in the object context, that's why I instantiated the model at the constructor of user class. 
a link to the task https://github.com/Thirdwrist/database-task

Comment: Can you point to the exact line number that is failing?

Comment: Are you sure you both want to `extend` the `Model` class AND have a reference to it? I suggest you read [this article on inheritance](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php)

Comment: It would also be worth looking into dependency injection and not creating things like connections in the constructor.

Comment: `$this->model = new Model;` is very peculiar

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections

Comment: on line 35 on the model class **$sql = "SELECT {$select} FROM {$this->table} {$where}";**

Comment: Yeah, that's due to all the crazy edit I had to do to try and make it work @Joas

Comment: You are calling non-static methods statically. Are you sure you want to do that? I'm pretty sure extending `Model` and having a reference to it is just wrong in this situation. The `Model` functions are not static, the `User` functions are. Take a good look at how you structured your models.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your connect class is in lowercase but you're importing it with uppercase "use Core\Connect;"
2. Since the namespace of the connect and model class is in the same namespace, you don't need to import it via "use Core\Connect;"
3. You referenced the table property in the Model class without setting it "$this->table;"
4. Since your User clas extends the Model class, why are you instantiaing the Model class inside the User constructor ?
5. Again you have a $table private property in the User class when you're still extending the Model class